# 500 error while entering some tables in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get error while entering some tables in phpmyadmin

```
Error in processing request 
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error
```

I can access other tables. But I am getting this error on some tables. what is the reason for this error? how can i solve?

Comment: Did you check your server's error log?

Comment: I can't login to phpmyadmin now. (phpmyadmin - Error)

Comment: You can check your server log without logging in to phpmyadmin

Comment: I am not an admin. how can I do that

Comment: You'll probably have to ask the person who does have administrative privileges. Which operating system and version is your server running? Which PHP and phpMyAdmin versions do you have?